# I upgraded to python 2.7 but google appengine reports that I have not

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I keep getting the message
A version of this application is using the Python 2.5 runtime, which is deprecated!
However I have definitely upgraded to python 2.7.
Could the be being reported incorrectly? I do not know what else I can do. I do not even have earlier versions on my machine.

Comment: I see know that though my application works fine on my localhost, and though I do not get an error when I deploy, the site is actually not updating. It is still showing the old version. Now I have in my appl.yami application: aussieclouds-hrd but it is just not deploying.

Comment: So what does the `runtime:` line in your `app.yaml` say?

Comment: @Martin Pieters - application: aussieclouds-hrd  
version: 1  
runtime: python27  
api_version:  
threadsafe: no
handlers:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have updated one or more newer version(s) of your app with `runtime: python27`, but likely failed to delete (or update) **older** versions you deployed back some time ago with `runtime: python`.

Note that the error message refers to

> **A** version of this application

not necessarily the default serving one, or the newest one, or whatever; **any** version of the application that's still deployed with the old Python 2.5 runtime is a danger, since that runtime is going away.

That, of course, is because you could, by visiting the appropriate URL, try running **any** currently deployed version of your app -- e.g

```
http://1-dot-yourappid.appspot.com/
```

would request the root URI from version 1.

So, delete or update **all** deployed versions of your app so any that remain deployed use Python 2.7, and you should be fine!

Comment: Thanks. But I tried going to http://1-dot-yourappid.appspot.com/ and I see an old page. It appears not to be updating. How do I delete all deployed versions?

Comment: @KathleenJuliff, to delete an old version, visit https://console.developers.google.com/project , pick the project, from left bar compute -> app engine -> versions, check the checkboxes of one or more non-default versions you want to delete (you can't delete the default version!), click the Delete button.   To update an old version instead of deleting it, set the `version:` directive in your app.yaml and `appconfig.py update` the app.